# How to modify EditField value on CheckBox action in InstallShield

Tags: installshield

I have EditField (it has global property EDITPROP) on the same window I have checkBox. I want to midify text that is visible in EditField when I check CheckBox.

I create action that modifies this property (EDITPROP) and run it on CheckBox click (as and DoAction). But when I click on CheckBox, I cannot see any changes in text on EditField.

What should I do in order to show this updated text on the EditField ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an MSI limitation that while EDITPROP will have the selected value as defined in the CheckBox table,  and UI elements using it ( [EDITPRO] ) won't refresh until you call NewDialog to go to the next dialog.  A work around for this behavior is to use ControlConditions to show/hide two mutually exclusive Text controls that use static text to represent the selected and unselected state.